Problem in add new lines for Whatsapp messages via Twilio Content Template Sending (Variable is a string with \n)
I'm trying to create a WhatsApp message with variables defined in Python. One of the variables is a string originating from a list that I append with a \n.
list = ["xxx", "yyy", "zzz"]
list = "\n".join(list)

And i pass it to twilio with:
message = client.messages.create( 
                              from_='whatsapp:+XXX',
                              content_sid='HXXX',
                              content_variables=json.dumps({                                
                              "1": list}),
                              to='whatsapp:+XXX',
                              messaging_service_sid='XXXXX')

The problem is with the \n. The message is not sent, resulting in error 63005.
The strange thing is that if I substitute \n with \f, it works on iPhones and the WhatsApp Desktop app, but not on Android or WhatsApp Web.
Is it possible to add new lines in a single variable in Twilio using Content Template Sending besides using \f?
I tried a lot of other possible solutions:

multi line string with """ """

from io import StringIO

os.linesep


etc.

I had this problem too, spent a couple of days debugging and I finally figured it out.
To solve this, you need to use \\n in join:
list = "\\n".join(list)

So the final json that you will send, will look like this:
'{"1": "xxx\\\\nyyy\\\\nzzz"}'

Bonus tip - if you want to put the values in bold, italics etc. you need to add proper sign for each value. So example for bold would be:
'{"1": "*xxx*\\\\n*yyy*\\\\n*zzz*"}'

